# Is there a way to run Worksheet_SelectionChange() Sub only after a set amount of time?

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a VBA code that will run on a range of cells in a worksheet. Every time a cell within that rnage is selected, I want the code to execute. I am doing this using:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

However, the code is quite slow and there are times I would like to navigate within that range using the arrow keys. To do so, I thought to use the Timer function that will only run the code if I am on a cell for more than 0.5 seconds.

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'set timer
Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
PauseTime = 0.6    ' Set duration.
Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
TotalTime = Finish - Start    ' Calculate total time.
If Abs(TotalTime) < 0.1 Then GoTo ws_exit

'continuation of code......

ws_exit:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The Main issue I am having with the code is that it is recursive and returns to the first timer that was set on the first cell I pressed. I wanted to know if there is a way to delay the SelectionChange code from running until the user is set on a cell for X amount of time.

Thanks,

Yon

Comment: Set `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top will prevent the recursive call of the event handler. However, as a consequence the code will continue to work even if the user already left the field.

Answer (score 0):

A class module solves this. Add a class module, call it cTimer. Paste this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Target As Range
Private StartTime As Double
Public WaitTime As Double

Public Sub HandlePrevious()
    If Timer - StartTime > WaitTime Then
        'Handle things now using Target
        Debug.Print Target.Address, "Taking action"
    Else
        Debug.Print Target.Address, "Moving on"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    StartTime = Timer
End Sub
```

Use this in your worksheet module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mcTimer As cTimer

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not mcTimer Is Nothing Then
        mcTimer.HandlePrevious
    End If
    Set mcTimer = Nothing
    Set mcTimer = New cTimer
    mcTimer.WaitTime = 0.5
    Set mcTimer.Target = Target
End Sub
```